# R Detecting and Replacing categorical strings

Tags: r, replace, stringr

I have a database about electric cars, and one column is Electric Utility. There are many variations for each company like

PUGEON ABC, PUGEON XLS, PUGEON ARR,
XIMAN RYR, XIMAN WET, XIMAN OPD.

and I just want to merge them all in one of each.

PUGEON - 3
XIMAN - 3.

This is how data looks.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQXcV.png)

I'm using STR Replace and STR Detect from String R package. I'll be replacing (all content) any column that has "BONEVILLE" word on it just with "Bonveille", but it tells me the object is not found. This is the code.

```
    evpd %>%
      mutate(str_replace(evpd$Electric.Utility, 
                         str_detect(string = Electric.Utility, pattern ="BONNEVILLE"), "Bonneville"))
```

Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: 1) Don't use `$`. 2) `... mutate(str_replace(Electric.Utility, "BONNEVILLE", "Bonneville"))` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @AndreWildberg, but it is replacing just the word, not the full sentence. There are BONNEVILLE A, BONNEVILLE B, and it is just replacing Bonneville, remaining the A and B. I want to replace all to create a category.

Comment: Ah ok. In this case try `... mutate(if_else(str_detect(Electric.Utility, "BONNEVILLE"), "Bonneville", Electric.Utility))`

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what the specific error is in your code without access to the dataset, but when using mutate, you usually don't want to use the `$` to reference a column.

I like using the function `ifelse()`, which would work similarly:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- 
  tibble(
    var1 = c('BONNEVILLE', 'BONNE VILLE', 'BONNEVILLE POWER')
  )
data
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>   var1            
#>   <chr>           
#> 1 BONNEVILLE      
#> 2 BONNE VILLE     
#> 3 BONNEVILLE POWER

data %>% 
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(str_detect(var1, 'BONNEVILLE'), 'Bonneville', var1))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>   var1       
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 Bonneville 
#> 2 BONNE VILLE
#> 3 Bonneville
```

Unfortunately this is a pretty difficult problem to solve I've found.  You could also checkout the `stringdist` package, which can help you compare similar strings.  Otherwise you might have to go through all unique categories and create a coding for them.